# Name for matrices $A$ such that $A^n = I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a special name for matrices $A$ (or generally elements of rings or even monoids) such that $$A^n = I\ ?$$

Or, more generally, is there a name for $f:S\to S$ such that $f^{\circ n}  = \operatorname{id}_S$ Where $f^{\circ n}(x) = \underbrace{f(\ldots f(x)\ldots )}_{n-\text{times}}$ is the repeated composition.

Or, *even more* generally, is there a name for elements $a \in M$ for monoids $(M,*,e)$ such that $a*a* \cdots *a = e$?

I am aware that we call them *nillpotent* if $A^n = 0$ for some $n$.

Comment: Probably *torsion matrix*?

Comment: For a ring in general, *multiplicative torsion* would be a name. In the case of fields they are called *roots of unity*.

Comment: If I recall correctly, *torsion point* = *points of finite order*, right?

Comment: Yes. The term *point* suggests geometry; I have only encountered the term *torsion point* in the context of elliptic curves and related subjects placing *group structures* on geometric objects. I haven't seen this usage for matrix rings or rings in general.

Comment: Right, I was influenced by this subject=) But generally I just wasn't sure, but apparently e.g. *torsion-subgroup* is used outside of this context.

Comment: The matrix is _periodic_. Note however that some periodic matrices are singular.
As a simple example consider any $(3\times 3)$ skew-symmetric matrix normalized such that $\;\big\|A\big\|^2_F=2.\;$ Then $\;A=A^{n+1}\;{\rm yet}\;I\ne A^n$

Answer (score 2):

In the theory of Lie algebras, derivations $D$ which satisfy $D^n=I$ are called **periodic**, see [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/publications.html). For non-abelian Lie algebras peridic derivations $D$ with $D^n=I$ only exists for $n$ being a multiple of six. I think this terminology is also used for all linear operators $A$ with $A^n=I$.

Comment: The term *periodic* absolutely makes sense, thanks!