# Matrices such that $A^k = A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Suppose $A$ is a matrix over a field such that $A^k = A$ for some $k$. Are there any standard name for this kind of matrices? (Like if $A^m = 0$ then $A$ is called nilpotent)

For $k = 2$ I know that they are called idempotent matrices.

In general what is the name?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, then $A^n=I$ for $n=k-1$. This has a name, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848682/name-for-matrices-a-such-that-an-i). As for common names of matrices, check [wikiepdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_named_matrices).

Comment: @mkcpz Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think it's called a k-potent matrix.